# How to share File across A Ubuntu Workstation to a Windows Workstation using a Debian server

Tags: networking, server, debian

So I want to share files from my Ubuntu workstation to my Windows 7 workstation. But I must share them through the use of a single Debian 9 server. I know i can use SAMBA to share from Ubuntu to windows but its a requirement to use Debian. Basically i need help setting this network up.

Comment: you problem is with debian not Ubuntu. Basically you need (/can do it with) openssh on debian but how to do that on debian is off topic :)